# Change queryset of model field in inlineformset of non parent model

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am using an inline formset and need to change the queryset of one of the non parent model's form fields when the formset is instantiated.

```
class Foo(Model):
   name = models.TextField()

class Bar(Model):
   foo = models.ForiegnKey(Foo)
   other_model = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel)

class BarForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model=Bar


foo = Foo.object.get(id=1)
FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Foo, Bar, form=BarForm)
formset = FormSet(instance=foo)
```

Depending on the value of foo which isn't determined until I enter the view code, I need to alter the queryset of the 'other_model' field in the BarForm for all forms in the formset.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you can do... You can override `BaseInlineFormSet`, then manually set the query set for that field on every form in the formset.

So in your forms.py, you would do this:

```
class BaseBarFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, other_model_queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseInlineFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for form in self.forms:
            form.fields['other_field'].queryset = other_model_queryset
```

Note how the first argument to __init__ is the queryset you want to set.

Then in you view, you would just modify your current code accordingly. Pass in that new BaseBarFormSet in the factory function:

```
FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Foo, Bar, form=BarForm, formset=forms.BaseBarFormSet) # notice formset=forms.BaseBarFormSet
```

Then pass the queryset you want for the other field to the actual `FormSet` class created by the factory function:

```
formset = FormSet(OtherModel.objects.filter(…), instance=foo) #notice the first parameter
```

Formsets are very complicated sometimes, so hopefully that made sense… let me know if you have problems.

Comment: That seems to solve the problem with the queryset.  I am however getting validation errors on my extra form even though it is unchanged.  I was under the impression that formsets would not do this.  From the django documentation "The formset is smart enough to ignore extra forms that were not changed."

Comment: You are right. You shouldn't get errors if the form is truly empty. You don't have any default values on your form or something do you?