# Filter foreign key queryset model in InlineFormSet

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i have two models

```
class Order:
    ...

class OrderItem:
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='products')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Product:
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

I create `InlineFormSet` from these models:

```
FormSet = inlineformset_factory(Order, OrderItem)
```

And in my view, i'm called it

```
formset = FormSet()
```

But i'm get all products in `product` ModelChoiceField. How can I filter products that the user has?

If I do so:

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, product_queryset=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if product_queryset:
            self.form.base_fields['product'].queryset = product_queryset

...

formset = FormSet(formset=BaseFormSet)
```

Everything works, but in documentation Django written

> Beware not to alter the base_fields attribute
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form

How can filter products without `base_fields`?

Comment: I'm found the solution, did the same as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305964/change-queryset-of-model-field-in-inlineformset-of-non-parent-model

Answer (score 1):

Use `self.form.fields` as shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.fields).

**Update in response to comment**

```
form = OrderItemForm()
form.product.queryset = Product.objects.filter(..filter here..)
formset = FormSet(formset=BaseFormSet, form=form)
```

Comment: it can only be used in the form, how to send queryset in the form from view?
`formset = FormSet(formset=BaseFormSet, form=Form(???))`

Comment: No, `FormSet()` doesn't work with keyword argument `form` and agrument `form` work only with `inlineformset_factory`, where his his takes reference to class